# npgsql executereader is slow when running in C# thread in cloud run

Tags: c#, postgresql, multithreading, npgsql

I have C# cloud run code that run and read data from postgres about 97 ms, when this code run in second thread inside cloud run it load data very slowly (about 28 sec).

I use NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader for reading data

Has anyone encountered this problem?

EDIT:

I have function that read data from 6 tables

when it run from a thread it read data very slowly, here some code:

```
while(true)
{
    try {
        if (_connection.Wait(60000))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Notification arrived");
            LoadGlobalParameters();
        }
    }
  
}
```

I call this function in the controller and the data read fast (for test only)

```
public static void LoadParameters()
        {
            ...
            PostgresDAL _postgres = new PostgresDAL();
            _postgres.Connect(new PostgreConnectionParameters()
            {
            });
            
            foreach (var param in Params)
            {
                var res = _postgres.ExecuteReaderCommand(param.ParamType, $"select * from {param.TableName}");
                sw_command.Stop();
                param.Items = res.Cast<IItem>().ToList();
            }
            sw_commands.Stop();
            lock (_lock)
            {
                _params = Params;
            }
        }
```

Comment: An [mcve] would be great here.

Comment: I add code, thanks

Comment: The above... isn't really a code sample that can help people understand what's going on. What's postgres.Wait? What's LoadGlobalParameters?